# How can I prevent this error from coming up when the user enters a string in python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7

```
loop =1
while loop==1:
    x = input('Enter 1 for CI, 2 for SI, 3 for Area of cylinder and 4 for area of circle:')

    if x==1:
        from math import*
        p = input('Enter Principal: ')
        r = input('Enter rate: ')
        n = input('Enter number of years: ')
        CI = p*pow((1+r),n)
        print 'The Compound Interest is:', CI
        print '\n'
    elif x==2:
        from math import*
        p = input('Enter Principal: ')
        r = input('Enter rate: ')
        n = input('Enter number of years: ')
        SI = (p*n*r)/100.0
        print 'The Simple Interest is:', SI
        print '\n'
    elif x==3:
        from math import*
        r = input('Enter radius of cylinder: ')
        h = input('Enter height of cylinder: ')
        A= 2*pi*r*(h+r)
        print 'The Area of Cylinder is:', A
        print '\n'

    elif x==4:
        from math import*
        r = input('Enter radius of circle:')
        A = pi*r*r
        print 'The Area of circle is:', A
        print '\n'

    else:
        print 'Enter 1,2,3 or 4:'
```

This is the error when user enter a string

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
   line 3, in <module>
    x = input('Enter 1 for CI, 2 for SI, 3 for Area of cylinder and 4 for area of circle:')
  File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'j' is not defined
```

Comment: You want to use `raw_input` and then explicitly try and convert the values to the appropriate type, eg: `r = float(raw_input('Enter radius of circle: '))`

Comment: I tried something like that and it didn't work. if the user enter a string i need it to prompt the user to enter 1,2,3 or 4 something like: elif isinstance(x,str):
    print 'invalid input'

Answer (score 2):

Before Python 3, `input` tries to [evaluate the input](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4915361/whats-the-difference-between-raw-input-and-input-in-python3-x) as a Python expression. If you type `j`, then it will try to find the name `j`, which fails.

Use `raw_input` instead, which does not do that evaluation, but returns a string: in that case you need to change your `if` conditions to test for a string:

```
if x == '1':
```

...etc.

Then for the other `input()` calls you could do the same, and then convert the string you get to float with:

```
p = float(raw_input('Enter Principal: '))
```

Of course, that could fail if the user enters non numerical data, which really is an error condition. You could put that in a `try` block and treat that error condition.

See the corrected script run on [repl.it](https://repl.it/FpJA)